# How to identify to customer is existing or not in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9

When we create an order with the new customer from the backend through then how to detect the programmatically user is existing or not?

I am triggering this event "sales_order_place_after" and  I have tried with below code but submit order then we will get the error: the customer is exist

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
        if ($websiteId) {
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        }
        $customer->loadByEmail($email);
        if ($customer->getId()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the checkout_success event

```xml
    <events>
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <observers>
                <abandonedcart_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>whatever/observer</class>
                    <method>doStuff</method>
                </abandonedcart_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    </events>
```

```
public function doStuff(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $orderIds));
    foreach ($collection as $order) {
        // do stuff
    }

}
```

To demonstrate what you could do you can put some test logic on success phtml to understand more about what's happening and how to tell difference between customers

app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/checkout/success.phtml

```php
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$quoteId = $order->getQuoteId();
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
$method = $quote->getCheckoutMethod(true);
$customer_email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
if ($method == 'register') { 
    //code to handle if customer just registered to your site
} elseif($method == 'guest') {
    //code to handle if customer is guest
} else {
    //code to handle for logged in customer
}
```

Your email check logic looks correct

```php
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->loadByEmail($customer_email);

if($customer && $customer->getId())
{
    // Customer Exist
}
```

Then if that all works focus your attention on the following events

`sales_order_place_before`

`adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data`

`sales_order_save_after`

Also maybe try under `<global>` scope instead of `<adminhtml>` scope

But I'm confused.  As part of the admin create process you need to select a customer record.

So they would never not exist.  That's why I included all this other stuff as thought perhaps there is a misunderstanding.

Comment: I already defined globally but not getting